# Tooltip to disabled button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

In

```
<%= link_to 'New', new_post_path,  
title: "Login or register to create post" , 
rel: "tooltip" , 
class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

it work fine , but if i add disabled in not work

```
<%= link_to 'New', new_post_path,  
title: "Login or register to create post" ,
rel: "tooltip" ,
class: "btn btn-primary disabled" %>
```

How to add Tooltip to disabled button ?

Comment: I dont think disabled is a class. Its supposed to be placed just before the greater than(>) symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled isn't a class. It's just a boolean option. Also, [Bootstrap hates tooltips on disabled buttons](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9294), to solve this, wrap it in a div:

```
<div title="Login or register to create post" rel="tooltip">
    <%= link_to 'New', new_post_path, class: "btn btn-primary", disabled: true %>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Disabled Primary</button>.

I tried  disabled: true , also work but without Tooltip

Comment: tooltip work but button was invisible
[link](http://www.imgonline.com.ua/result_img/imgonline-com-ua-twotooneln9VjM0egRFl.jpg)

Comment: @SerhiiDanovskyi try again?